# Can Redis or Memcached be used to "lock" a resource such as a blobstore like S3?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, memcached, redis, distributed-computing

Would like to "lock" an external resource, in this case it will be a "blob" stored on [rackspace cloud servers](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/public/files/), similar so Amazon S3. (Using Python)

Would like a race condition to be handled like this:

- First process creates lock on resource
- First process begins editing resource
- Second process attempts to edit the same resource and finds that the resource is locked.
- Second process requests to be notified when the lock is taken off
- First process finishes editing the resource and removes the lock
- Second process receives the notification of the freed resource and is able to make its own edits

Would like to use Memcached or Redis to create the lock, however a different mechanism would be fine as well.

Most of this is pretty simple, the part I am struggling with is how to notify the second process when the lock is removed as opposed to forcing it to wait and retry.

Redis has [publish / subscribe functionality](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub), would this be appropriate to use in this situation?

Or is there some other way that I should go about solving this problem?

Thanks so much!

Comment: look at http://www.davidverhasselt.com/2011/08/06/a-distributed-mutex-and-semaphore-using-redis/

Comment: Usually the second process would just loop until the lock set by the first process is freed — is this absolutely not a possibility? (and why?) otherwise implementing this algorithm would be relatively straightforward using redis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for Redis, in case you really need to have locking, you can use `SETNX` to create such a lock, more information can be found in [SETNX documentation](http://redis.io/commands/setnx).

If you expect low contention for the given lock and also you don't have any resource hungry processing for the locked information you can also use `WATCH`/`MULTI`/`EXEC` transactions. First you set WATCH on the key you want to edit, then in `MULTI` you edit the key itself and then finally after `EXEC`, it either fails the edit because someone meanwhile edited that watched key (and you then need to retry) or it return OK and you are fine. This is how you implement opportunistic locking in Redis. More info in [transaction documentation](http://redis.io/topics/transactions)